How to remove the weird dots in grid-like pattern

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eVAzBuTpyHvcMq2-e7vNIy8jIGd_pa3P/view?usp=drive_link
The dots first appeared when i transferred my object from an older version of blender to 4.2

That link requests access so we can't download your file but that looks like a graphics driver problem to me. Check that your drivers are up to date and that your graphics card is supported under Blender 4.2.

And now that you've allowed access it's not showing any problem here using Blender 4.2.3 so I reckon it's a graphics problem on your machine as I suggested before.

I opened your model. I don't have any points on the mesh like you do. Maybe it's on the texture (there is no texture in your file).
Try the following options:

import the model
run Append
create a new scene > open > disable Load UI in the settings

This is what came to mind.

I think the problem was my graphics drivers like John Eason suggested. I created an entirely new scene/model and the problem appeared there as well.
